# Loop through an array and use the result of each loop as a variable for inserting to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have an input form which includes a list box where multiple items can be selected:

```
<select name="MultiRoomSelect[]" id="MultiRoomSelect" multiple="multiple">
```

I am trying to read the content of `$_POST['MultiRoomSelect']` and use the result to look up records in a table.

For testing the result of `MultiRoomSelect[]` is `"2,3,4"` which are the correct ID's for the record(s) lookup I want to execute.

The lookup query I have is

```
SELECT RecordID, RoomID FROM Jafa WHERE RoomID =
```

It's the = part I am very unsure about, how can I use the result of the `MultiRoomSelect[]` to populate a variable I can use in the query like:

```
SELECT RecordID, RoomID FROM Jafa WHERE RoomID = $value //MultiRoomSelect[]
```

and keep looping until the array has read all three array values.

I hope I have written this clearly. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you could use the `in` selector method - such as `select * from jafa where roomid in (2,3,4) ` etc ~ implode would be handy there too!

Comment: @RamRaider Hi, I am using "explore" like $MultiRoomID = $_POST['MultiRoomSelect'];
$MultiRoomIDResult = implode(',',$MultiRoomID); but how do I use the $MultiRoomIDResult. 2,3,4 is only an example,MultiRoomSelect[] could contain any set of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I meant:

```
$ids=$_POST['MultiRoomSelect'];

$sql="select `RecordID`, `RoomID` from `Jafa` where `RoomID` in ( ".implode( ',', $ids )." );";



/* Query the db once: pseudo code */
$results = $db->query( $sql );

/* Process recordset */
while( $rs = $result->fetch() ){
    /* show records etc*/
}
```

Which would yield the final sql as:

```
select `RecordID`, `RoomID` from `Jafa` where `RoomID` in ( 1,2,3 );
```

Using the following form to test

```
    <form method='post'  action='/test/target.php'>
        <h1>Multi-Select SQL</h1>
        <select name="MultiRoomSelect[]" id="MultiRoomSelect" multiple="multiple">
        <?php
            for( $i=1; $i < 100; $i++ ) echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i;
        ?>
        </select>
        <input type='hidden' name='section' value='multiselectsql' />
        <input type='submit' id='sub' value='Submit'>
    </form>
```

And randomly selecting a large range of non-contiguous numbers generated the following sql:

```
select `RecordID`, `RoomID` from `Jafa` where `RoomID` in ( 46,47,48,49,50,56,57,58,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,74,76,78,80,82,84,86,88,90,92,93,96 );
```

Comment: when I run the script the result of the loop lookup is: 2,3,4
Array ( [RecordID] => 27 [RoomID] => 2 [RoomName] => Room 1) Array ( [RecordID] => 27 [RoomID] => 2 [RoomName] => Room 1 ) Array ( [RecordID] => 27 [RoomID] => 2 [RoomName] => Room 1. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You wouldn't need to query in a loop, just a single query which will produce the recordset for all records whose `roomid` matches the `in` statement. Thus, if you have `roomid`'s of 2,3,4 there would be three rows in the recordset... have i misunderstood?

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already `imploded` the result and have everything required inside `$MultiRoomIDResult`.

You can use a simple `IN` clause like @RamRaider mentioned.

```
SELECT * FROM jafa where roomid IN ($MultiRoomIDResult);
```

Comment: @Kostas Mitsarakis, I used roomid IN ($MultiRoomIDResult) but the loop only looks at the first RoomID three times and returns the lookup result the same, three records the same. I know that for testing $MultiRoomIDResult contains 2,3,4 and there are records in the lookup table with id's the same.